# Exception: 401 Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential

Tags: python-3.x, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, github-actions

I've seen a few people over the years facing similar issue but I haven't found much regarding my case.

I have a backend built with python3.

- I am using `firebase_admin` as a library to connect to Firebase Cloud Firestore.
- I then commit my code to Github and using Github Actions
- I am deploying the docker container to Google Cloud Run.
- This all works fine for some time
- Some time later throws the following exception: `Exception: 401 Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.`

What am I doing wrong?

- Should I connect every time I call the function? (move the db initialization in each function call)
- Feels like the token expired. Can I refresh it somehow?

Python code:

```py
from firebase_admin import firestore, initialize_app

initialize_app()
db = firestore.client()

def get_info_from_firestore(name: str:
   try:
        data = db.collection(u'data').where(u'title', u'==', name).stream()
        for rating in ratings:
            return rating.to_dict()
        return None
    except Exception as e:
        logging.warning(Exception: {e}')
        return None
```

And this file is imported from my root python file that's using Flask.

Edit: One final thing that might help, if I redeploy my container without any changes it all works again.

Comment: I would expect that the token will get refreshed automatically and you don't need to manage it manually. I am not sure but this behavior may be specific to Cloud Run and its [limited access to resources](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tips#avoiding_background_activities) during idle state which prevents the refreshing. Reinitializing the connection during each call should solve this then.

Answer (score 0):

Likely this is happening due to time drift: time in docker significatly differs realtime. After restart time is in sync but after a while it drifts. Google does not like it. See more info about this WSL/container issue here https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4245 and here https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/4526